# change burger menu when click on link

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In the code below, when I click on the burger menu, the design changes from burger to an X and the menu opens successfully. However, when I click on a link within the menu, the menu does close BUT the X menu does NOT change its design back to a burger.In other words, the menu closes but the css of the icon does not change back. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
  const handleClick = (event: any) => {
    if (!menuOpen) {
      event.currentTarget.classList.add("open");
      setMenu(true);
    } else {
      event.currentTarget.classList.remove("open");
      setMenu(false);
    }
  };
```

```
  <div className="mt-4 container page-container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="d-grid gap-2 pb-3 col-4 mx-auto ">
          <div className="menu-btn" onClick={handleClick}>
            <div className="menu-btn_burger"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {menuOpen && (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="d-grid gap-2 pt-3 col-6 mx-auto ">
            <Link to="/add" onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm  ">
              Add Task
            </Link>
            <Link to="/" onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
              All Reminders <span className="badge badge-light text-dark">{tasks.length > 0 && tasks.length}</span>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from the event target

In the first case, the target is the div with class menu-button but in the second case, it is referring to the link element.

How to solve it?

Use Refs

```
const menuRef = useRef(null);
const handleClick = (event: any) => {
if (!menuOpen) {
  menuRef.current.classList.add("open");
  setMenu(true);
} else {
  menuRef.current.classList.remove("open");
  setMenu(false);
}
};


<div className="mt-4 container page-container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="d-grid gap-2 pb-3 col-4 mx-auto ">
      <div ref={menuRef} className="menu-btn" onClick={handleClick}>
        <div className="menu-btn_burger"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {menuOpen && (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="d-grid gap-2 pt-3 col-6 mx-auto ">
        <Link to="/add" onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm  ">
          Add Task
        </Link>
        <Link to="/" onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          All Reminders <span className="badge badge-light text-dark">{tasks.length > 0 && tasks.length}</span>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>}
```

see more in the official docs
[React Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: That looks good except for the menuRef.classList. I get this error: "Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>'.ts(2339)" Any suggestions?

Comment: you may need to add .current property to the menuref. I'll edit my answer now

Comment: @MichaelHorvilleur did my solution solve your problem?

Comment: Kind of. The issue was with typescript. The answer is here:  https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/issues/187